# How to turn scraped data into a JSON object using cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json, cheerio

This is my code:

```
let request = require('request');
let cheerio = require('cheerio');

let url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/marketinfo/companyTracker/compInfo.jsp?symbol=INFY&series=EQ"
request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        let $ = cheerio.load(html);
        tabCon = $('td').text(),
        console.log(tabCon);
    }
})
```

I am getting output on my console like this:

> Infosys LimitedDate of Listing (NSE) : 08-Feb-1995Face Value :         5.00ISIN : INE009A01021Industry : COMPUTERS - SOFTWAREConstituent Indices : ,NIFTY 500,NIFTY IT,NIFTY 50,NIFTY 100,NIFTY 200,NIFTY SERVICES SECTORIssued Cap. :       4258456678(shares) as on 25-Nov-2019Free Float Market Cap. *:   253866.09(Cr) Impact Cost:    0.01 as on Nov-201952 week high/low price : 847.00/599.85*  Free-float market capitalization as on the previous trading day.

I want to put this data into a JSON (not file) in this structure:

```
{
"Date of Listing (NSE)": "08-Feb-1995",
"Face Value": "5.00",
"ISIN": "INE009A01021".......and so on
}
```

Comment: This might help https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/1113#issuecomment-348809254

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `.filter()` method to exclude all `td` elements without `:` (key-value pair indicator), then having initialized an object variable, iterate through the resulting elements to build the object as follows:

```
....
request(url, function(error, response, html){
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    let $ = cheerio.load(html);
    let tabCon = {};
    $('td').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).text().indexOf(':') > -1; 
    }).each(function() {
        let kvPair = $(this).text().split(':');
        tabCon[kvPair[0].trim()] = kvPair[1].trim();
    });
    console.log(tabCon);
  }
});
```